# How to Access a ngInit Value from ngRepeat in Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my `infoDisplay(member)` I need to access the ng-init value specific to the div that I clicked on from the $scope and manipulate the value. How do I do so?

```
<div ng-repeat="member in memberData">
    <div class="card" ng-init="cardClicked = 'false'">
        <div ng-click="infoDisplay(member)">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
$scope.infoDisplay = function (member) {
    if (settings.useApiInfo == 'false') {
        var url = settings.directoryUrl + member.Id;
        var openUrl = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_system', 'location = yes');
    }
    else {
        cardClicked = { 'true': 'false', 'false': 'true' }[cardClicked];
    }
}
```

The first part works, it is to open a url in my mobile app. I just need the second part but can't get it working.

Comment: Just pass cardClicked in as well: `infoDisplay(memeber, cardClicked)`?

Comment: @opticon That would only access cardClicked in your function and wouldn't affect the scope variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is set the flag on the item itself:

```
<div ng-repeat="member in memberData">
    <div class="card" ng-init="member.cardClicked = false">
        <div ng-click="infoDisplay(member)">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can acces it in your controller:

```
$scope.infoDisplay = function(member) {
    var cardClicked = member.cardClicked;
}
```

If you think that your `cardClicked` shouldn't be on your `member` item, just track the values in an array:

```
<div ng-repeat="member in memberData">
    <div class="card" ng-init="cardsClicked[$index] = false">
        <div ng-click="infoDisplay(member, $index)">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can acces it in your controller:

```
$scope.infoDisplay = function(member, index) {
    var cardClicked = $scope.cardsClicked[index];
}
```